# Avoid multiple outputs of same record in CSV?

Tags: python, csv, output

I am using Python 2.7.12 on windows 10 (64 bit).
I have a list:
`t = ('1','2','3','4','5')`

I want to send the output to csv file in column (and not in row). I used following code:

```
import os, csv, itertools
for m, v in itertools.product(t, t):
    for i in range(1,11):
        if m != v:
            mvb = '%s_%s_%dB'%(m,v,i)
            data = [[mvb]]
            f = open('C:\ha\Pyout.csv','ab')
            for row in data:
                for columns in row:
                    f.write('%s,'%columns)
            f.close()
```

This code is sending the desired output in csv file in column (and not in row), but multiple time. I mean the title `'5_4_10B'` is repeated at the beginning and at the end many times.
I am unable to find the problem.

Comment: You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try your question again.

Comment: thanks, pstaix. I made the changes.

Comment: Dear martinau. Thanks for editing. Many thanks. Upvote for your help. The problem was with indentation for the line 'if m!=v:". I decreased the indentation by one space and I got the desired output. Your editing is behind this.